# Java JAAS integration with Linux PAM including password aging

Tags: java, jaas, pam

**Background**

In our project we are using our custom `LoginModule` implementation to integrate JAAS for a web application with server's Linux PAM. I know there are projects implementing PAM for JAAS but that is not the point here especially that they do not solve my problem.

Now requirement came to properly handle password aging and shadow status.

So user that tries to login (using web form) with password that is:

- *expired* should be denied access and get a message asking to contact administrator to renew account,
- *inactive* should be denied access and get a message asking to change his password using SSH,
- *in warning period* should be granted access but get a message informing how many days remain before the password will have to be changed.

Those are normal behaviours for PAM that show up with SSH for example. (Note however that it depends on PAM configuration and account settings.)

**The Problem**

I can easily obtain required information in our custom `LoginModule`. So I will know the status (expired, inactive, warning, ...) and number of days remaining (if applicable).

But how to propagate it further?

The expired/inactive distinction could be made by carefully picking exception thrown from the `LoginModule` implementation. This isn't perfect since if some middle layer consumes the exceptions to rethrow something else I will be in trouble again. But I guess it is doable.

But how about the warning period? Exception is no way since it is successful login. But I still need to provide the extra information that this password is in warning period and how many days are remaining.

The only means of communication out of `LoginModule` I see is to add something to the `Subject`. But what I have to add doesn't seem neither `Principal` nor a credential.

Sure I could just push my custom object as a credential or custom `Principal` implementation. But it doesn't seem to be "natural". It looks more like breaking the design. I didn't even found any example of anyone doing something like this.

So how would I do that? What are the means of communicating out of the `LoginModule` additional information on the account?

**Workaround**

As for now I came out with a workaround. I could do required queries on PAM/NSS to determine password status and days remaining (if applicable) either in a servlet filter or controller. It is not even more difficult - the same calls have to be done in the end.

But it doesn't seem the proper way of solving it because it mixes responsibilities.

So what else could I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve, but it is not responsibility of `LoginModule` to deal with password state and it is not what `JAAS` was designed for.

Because of that I think your workaround is the way to go. If its easy for you to obtain additional information in `LoginModule` then create a field there or pass an object where you will store that data and access it whenever it needs to be rendered to user. - **KISS**